# Find every Sunday between two dates

Tags: php

I have `$fromdate` and `$todate` variables. I want a function that can calculate the dates of each Sunday existing in between `$fromdate` and `$todate` in PHP.

Comment: This seems trivial to the point that it might be homework. Not sure, though.

Comment: Hmm...if I remember correctly, I think this is a Project Euler question.

Answer (score 11):

Assuming these are date objects, start at $fromdate, add one day to it, until that date is Sunday, and as long as the date is before $todate.  Add 7 days to each Sunday you find, add that date and continue as long as the new date is before $todate.  Keep track of each date found this way.

Answer (score 8):

Use this function:

```
function getDateForSpecificDayBetweenDates($startDate, $endDate, $weekdayNumber)
{
    $startDate = strtotime($startDate);
    $endDate = strtotime($endDate);

    $dateArr = array();

    do
    {
        if(date("w", $startDate) != $weekdayNumber)
        {
            $startDate += (24 * 3600); // add 1 day
        }
    } while(date("w", $startDate) != $weekdayNumber);


    while($startDate <= $endDate)
    {
        $dateArr[] = date('Y-m-d', $startDate);
        $startDate += (7 * 24 * 3600); // add 7 days
    }

    return($dateArr);
}
```

The function call to get dates for all Sunday's in year 2010:

```
$dateArr = getDateForSpecificDayBetweenDates('2010-01-01', '2010-12-31', 0);

print "<pre>";
print_r($dateArr);
```

The reuslt:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2010-01-03
    [1] => 2010-01-10
    [2] => 2010-01-17
    [3] => 2010-01-24
    [4] => 2010-01-31
    [5] => 2010-02-07

     ................
     ................
     ................

    [47] => 2010-11-28
    [48] => 2010-12-05
    [49] => 2010-12-12
    [50] => 2010-12-19
    [51] => 2010-12-26
)
```

Comment: $startDate += (7 * 24 * 3600); // add 7 days  

should be:  

$startDate = strtotime("+1 week", $startDate); // add 7 days

Comment: @Bokw is correct, else it gives me the last days wrong.

Comment: @dxb_dev how to count Saturday and Sunday both current output is only Sunday. Thanks

Comment: hi there, nice answer ... can you guide me .. how can apply 2 weekends ... i try it .. but its not working

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
function getDateForSpecificDayBetweenDates($start, $end, $weekday = 0){

$weekdays="Sunday,Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday,Saturday";

$arr_weekdays=split(",", $weekdays);
$weekday = $arr_weekdays[$weekday];
if(!$weekday)
    die("Invalid Weekday!");

$start= strtotime("+0 day", strtotime($start) );
$end= strtotime($end);

$dateArr = array();
$friday = strtotime($weekday, $start);
while($friday <= $end)
{
    $dateArr[] = date("Y-m-d", $friday);
    $friday = strtotime("+1 weeks", $friday);
}
$dateArr[] = date("Y-m-d", $friday);

return $dateArr;
}
```

Here's how this function can be called...

```
$dateArr = getDateForSpecificDayBetweenDates("Today", "+1 year", 0); // 0 Sun, 1 Mon, etc.
```

`$start` and `$end` dates will take anything that `strtotime()` supports.

Answer (score -1):

PHPs [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) and [mktime()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php) functions should get you there!