# How to specific number of dates except sunday and saturday?

Tags: php, date

I need to get an array of dates except sunday and optional saturday by a specific day count... I found a cool thing - [dateperiod](http://php.net/manual/ru/class.dateperiod.php), witch gives array to me, but how to exclude sunday and saturday?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074086/find-every-sunday-between-two-dates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
$daterange = new DatePeriod(...);
$weekdays = [];
foreach($daterange as $date){
    if ($date->format("N") < 6) array_push($weekdays, $date);
}
```

`$weekdays` should now contain every `date` object that isn't the 6th or greater day of the week (that is, Saturday or Sunday)

Answer (score 0):

As Simon M says, that seems to be the solution to this issue, it has been answered here too  [Get date range between two dates excluding weekends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352712/get-date-range-between-two-dates-excluding-weekends)

It's a bit disconcerting there's not an option on DatePeriod to exclude days.