# get date of all sunday between two date PHP Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

**What I want** 
want to do is add task on **every Sunday** from date 1 to 31 of any month(or between any two random date),so how to get date of every Sunday ?

**what i did** for now is like:

```
for(i=start_date;i<end-date;i++ ){
    if(check i.th date == 'Sunday'){
       take date of i;
    }
}
```

also posted here: http://wonderphp.wordpress.com/2014/09/18/add-recurring-task-php/

but i think its the long way to do so. so any quick trick? even in mysql

Answer (score 2):

Try this one.You can print the date by this way.You can replace the task `echo $day` as you want.

```
    $start_date = $_POST['start_date'];
    $end_date = $_POST['end_date'];

    $day = $start_date;
    do {
        list($day, $month, $year) = explode("-", $date);

    $wkday = date('l',mktime('0','0','0', $month, $day, $year));
        if($wkday == "sunday"){
        echo $day;
        }
        $day++;
    } while ($day < $end_date);
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work for you

```
$i=date("d",strtotime("today"));//your month first sunday like "january first sunday"    
while($i<30){
    i+=7;
}
```

Edit : iF you want something more than do this

```
 $i=date("d",strtotime("today"));//your month first sunday like "january first sunday"    
 $sundays=array();
    while($i<30){
         array_push($sundays,$i);
         //set event
         i+=7;
     }

 for($j=$startdate;$j<$enddate;$j++){
     if($j ,$sundays){
    //add task
     }   
 }
```

Comment: You wanted to add task on every sunday of the month so this will defiantly work.

Answer (score 1):

This might wil help you:

```
$start_date=strtotime("01 Sept 2014");
$end_date=strtotime("30 Sept 2014");
while(1){
  $start_date=strtotime('next sunday', $start_date);
  if($start_date>$end_date)
    break;
  echo "Next Sunday: ".date("d M Y",$start_date)."</br>";

}
```

Comment: If 01 Sept 2014 is sunday, This function skip first day

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
function getDateForSpecificDayBetweenDates($start, $end, $weekday = 0){
  $weekdays="Sunday,Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday,Saturday";
  $arr_weekdays=split(",", $weekdays);
  $weekday = $arr_weekdays[$weekday];
  if(!$weekday)
    die("Invalid Weekday!");
  $start= strtotime("+0 day", strtotime($start) );
  $end= strtotime($end);
  $dateArr = array();
  $friday = strtotime($weekday, $start);
  while($friday <= $end) {
    $dateArr[] = date("Y-m-d", $friday);
    $friday = strtotime("+1 weeks", $friday);
  }
  $dateArr[] = date("Y-m-d", $friday);
  return $dateArr;
}
$dateArr = getDateForSpecificDayBetweenDates("Today", "+1 year", 0); //0 Sun, 1 Mon, etc.
print_r($dateArr);
```

it will gives you all dates of sunday between two dates:-

```
Array ( [0] => 2014-09-28 [1] => 2014-10-05 [2] => 2014-10-12 [3] => 2014-10-19 [4] => 2014-10-26 [5] => 2014-11-02 [6] => 2014-11-09 [7] => 2014-11-16 [8] => 2014-11-23 [9] => 2014-11-30 [10] => 2014-12-07 [11] => 2014-12-14 [12] => 2014-12-21 [13] => 2014-12-28 [14] => 2015-01-04 [15] => 2015-01-11 [16] => 2015-01-18 [17] => 2015-01-25 [18] => 2015-02-01 [19] => 2015-02-08 [20] => 2015-02-15 [21] => 2015-02-22 [22] => 2015-03-01 [23] => 2015-03-08 [24] => 2015-03-15 [25] => 2015-03-22 [26] => 2015-03-29 [27] => 2015-04-05 [28] => 2015-04-12 [29] => 2015-04-19 [30] => 2015-04-26 [31] => 2015-05-03 [32] => 2015-05-10 [33] => 2015-05-17 [34] => 2015-05-24 [35] => 2015-05-31 [36] => 2015-06-07 [37] => 2015-06-14 [38] => 2015-06-21 [39] => 2015-06-28 [40] => 2015-07-05 [41] => 2015-07-12 [42] => 2015-07-19 [43] => 2015-07-26 [44] => 2015-08-02 [45] => 2015-08-09 [46] => 2015-08-16 [47] => 2015-08-23 [48] => 2015-08-30 [49] => 2015-09-06 [50] => 2015-09-13 [51] => 2015-09-20 [52] => 2015-09-27 )
```

For more :- [Find every Sunday between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074086/find-every-sunday-between-two-dates)

Comment: he wants the date on each sunday, not total sunday count of a month.

Comment: Wait if i can find something.

Comment: Will you check and modify this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4293174/grab-all-wednesdays-in-a-given-month-in-php

Answer (score 0):

This will helps to find all sundays between two dates

```
$startdate='2014-05-17';
$enddate='2014-09-20';

getSundays($startdate,$enddate);

function getSundays($startdate,$enddate) {
    $startweek=date("W",strtotime($startdate));
    $endweek=date("W",strtotime($enddate));
    $year=date("Y",strtotime($startdate));

    for($i=$startweek;$i<=$endweek;$i++) {
        $result=getWeek($i,$year);
        if($result>$startdate&&$result<$enddate) {
            echo "Sunday:".$result."<br>";
        }
    }
}

function getWeek($week, $year) {
  $dto = new DateTime();
  $result = $dto->setISODate($year, $week, 0)->format('Y-m-d');
  return $result;
}
```

Comment: I guess this is the answer :)

Comment: I have two question for you 1) is that short method ? 2) i have added $startdate='2014-09-01';$enddate='2014-09-30'; but the result is : Sunday:2014-08-31
Sunday:2014-09-07
Sunday:2014-09-14
Sunday:2014-09-21
Sunday:2014-09-28
so thats wrong