# how to include sunday in datetime column if sunday date not in record

Tags: sql

this is my query.

```
SELECT atdate,format(atdate,'ddd') as att_date,LvType FROM leavtran 
   WHERE AtDate between ('2019-02-01') and ('2019-02-28')
```

[image]

I want an add Sunday in the DateTime column.

Comment: Why only Sunday, there seems to be more dates/days missing in your output?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using

Comment: I think that at first you need to get sundays between your 2 dates. Then add them into the table. Please check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/37411453/6068342

Comment: Create a calendar table storing all dates of interest. outer join.

Comment: Obviously there aren't any dates that occurs on Sundays in the `leavtran` table between those dates. You just want to add them? What should be the result in the `LvType` column for those dates?

Answer (score 0):

You want *all* days in February.  Basically, this suggests a `LEFT JOIN`.  You don't mention the database, but the idea is something like this:

```
SELECT dt.atdate, FORMAT(dt.atdate, 'ddd') as att_date, lt.LvType
FROM (SELECT '2019-02-01' as dte UNION ALL
      SELECT '2019-02-02' as dte UNION ALL
      . . .
      SELECT '2019-02-28' as dte
     ) d LEFT JOIN
     leavtran lt
     ON lt.AtDate = d.dte ;
```

In your particular case, you could also just use `UNION ALL` with the Sunday dates:

```
SELECT lt.atdate, format(lt.atdate,'ddd') as att_date, lt.LvType
FROM leavtran 
WHERE lt.AtDate BETWEEN '2019-02-01' AND '2019-02-28'
UNION ALL
SELECT '2019-02-03', 'Sun', NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT '2019-02-10', 'Sun', NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT '2019-02-17', 'Sun', NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT '2019-02-24', 'Sun', NULL
ORDER BY atdate;
```