# Return minutes of sunday between two date php

Tags: php

I want to calculate all Sunday's minutes between two given dates.

```
 function getWeekEnd($startDate, $endDate)
  {
    $working_hours = [
        [0, 86400], // Sun
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null //Sat
    ];
    $start = new \DateTime($startDate);
    $end = new \DateTime($endDate);
    $seconds = 0; // Total working seconds
    // Calculate the Start Date (Midnight) and Time (Seconds into day) as Integers.
    $start_date = clone $start;
    $start_date = $start_date->setTime(0, 0, 0)->getTimestamp();
    $start_time = $start->getTimestamp() - $start_date;
    // Calculate the Finish Date (Midnight) and Time (Seconds into day) as Integers.
    $end_date = clone $end;
    $end_date = $end_date->setTime(0, 0, 0)->getTimestamp();
    $end_time = $end->getTimestamp() - $end_date;
    // For each Day
    for ($today = $start_date; $today <= $end_date; $today += 86400) {
        // Get the current Weekday.
        $today_weekday = date('w', $today);
        // Skip to next day if no hours set for weekday.
        if (!isset($working_hours[$today_weekday][0]) || !isset($working_hours[$today_weekday][1])) continue;
        // Set the office hours start/finish.
        $today_start = $working_hours[$today_weekday][0];
        $today_end = $working_hours[$today_weekday][1];
        // Adjust Start/Finish times on Start/Finish Day.
        if ($today === $start_date) $today_start = min($today_end, max($today_start, $start_time));
        if ($today === $end_date) $today_end = max($today_start, min($today_end, $end_time));
        // Add to total seconds.
        $seconds += $today_end - $today_start;
    }
    $time = date('H:i', $seconds);
    $hms = explode(":", $time);
    return ($hms[0] + ($hms[1]/60));
  }
```

For the moment i have this but if i make 2019-11-22 22:00:00 to 2019-11-28 10:00:00 i have no return do you have another function or fix this function ?

Thank a lot

Comment: just try to find sundays between dates and then multiply by 24*60 :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37411281/how-to-get-sunday-date-between-two-date

Comment: https://3v4l.org/XJ8fX

Comment: @AnantSingh---AlivetoDie Thx for reply but if date end or date start is on 12hours or 16 hours the fonction return 24 hours but is 12 hours of sunday

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try something like this:

```
<?php

function getSundayMinutes($dateFromString, $dateToString)
{
    $dateFrom = new \DateTime($dateFromString);
    $dateTo = new \DateTime($dateToString);
    $minutes = [
    "total" => 0
    ];

    if ($dateFrom > $dateTo) {
        return $minutes;
    }

    if (1 != $dateFrom->format('N')) {
        $dateFrom->modify('next sunday');
    }

    while ($dateFrom <= $dateTo) {
        $minutes[$dateFrom->format('Y-m-d')] = 1440;
        $minutes["total"] += 1440; 
        $dateFrom->modify('+1 week');
    }

    return $minutes;
}

$dateFromString = '2019-11-01';
$dateToString = '2019-11-19';
print_r(getSundayMinutes($dateFromString, $dateToString));

?>
```

As there were 3 sundays in november, above code will print out:

```
Array ( [total] => 4320 [2019-11-03] => 1440 [2019-11-10] => 1440 [2019-11-17] => 1440 )
```

I used the code from here [php function for get all mondays within date range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7061802/php-function-for-get-all-mondays-within-date-range)

BR

Comment: Thank for you reply but if the date end is on 12 hours he return 24 hours but is 12 hours